# Creating an inline table within a table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I am trying to display a piece of text inside a dynamically created table (the outer table). Inside the outer table are spans that are acting as spacers. I am trying to display a long string inline with the spans. However when the string wraps to the next line it starts at the beginning of the page. I need it to display vertically aligned to where the text started on the first line.

I dont have any control of the spans as those are dynamically created so I cannot add extra styling to those. My solution is to add a inner table as shown inside one of the outer table cells and display it inline with the span spacers.

The code below is starting the table on the second line, below the span spacers even though I have set the style property of display to inline-table.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table style="width:500px;">
    <tr>
      <td><span style="padding:50px"></span><span style="padding:50px"></span>
        <table style="display:inline-table; vertical-align:top">
          <tr>
            <td>
              HERE IS MY SENTENCE HERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE
              IS MY SENTENCE.
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

The final output should look something like this.

```
                             HERE IS MY SENTENCE HERE IS MY 
                             SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY 
                             SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY 
                             SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY 
                             SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY 
                             SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY 
                             SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY 
                             SENTENCE.
```

Comment: any updates with the question?

Comment: None that work for my situation

Answer (score 0):

Try the following snippet. Also removed all inline styling.

```
 table {
        width: 300px;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
```

OR

```
 table {
        width: 50%;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
    }
```

```css
table {
  width: 300px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td><span style="padding:50px"></span><span style="padding:50px"></span>
        <table>
          <tr>
            <td>
              HERE IS MY SENTENCE HERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE IS MY SENTENCEHERE
              IS MY SENTENCE.
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It works okay but I cannot remove the two span tags from the original post as they are dynamically generated. And the text needs to be displayed next them.

Comment: I added the span tags now. But i think you don't need any styling over there, since external style sheet is handling it